# Calculate the voltage between terminals a and b

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Calculate the voltage between terminals a and b before and after connecting the external resistance R, then calculate absolute and relative difference of these voltages.
[image]

Comment: Please note that we don't work out homework problems here.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first situation, no current is flowing: it's an open circuit. Any voltage drop is caused purely by that voltage source in the circuit.

In the second situation, however, they're connected, so current is flowing. You know that the voltage drop between the front and back of the voltage source is 6 volts, because of Kirchoff's voltage law; from that, you should be able to use Ohm's law to find the current around the circuit and hence the voltage drop over the external resistor.

Comment: Please don't answer homework questions when the OP hasn't made any effort.

Comment: This is not my homework